# Terminal with iTerm (Mac) like label

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Is there a terminal for elementary with the "badge feature" like iTerm for Mac?
With many open terminal windows it is very helpful to see the current terminal informations in the right top corner of a terminal.

If you don't know iTerm badge have a look [here](http://dasari.me/2016/08/29/iterm-badges.html). Especially the second picture:
[image]

If nobody knows a linux alternative maybe this could be nice feature request for (not only pantheon-)terminal.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a terminal for elementary with the "badge feature" like iTerm
>   for Mac?

I'm not aware of any Linux terminals with that will display a "badge" in the upper right-hand corner, but Linux terminals can display some of the same information.

From the link you provided:

> We can display some dynamic status like the current user, host name or
>   git branch.

The username and host name should be displayed in the terminal prompt by default. It should also display the directory that you are in. There are some good sites out there on how to configure the prompt:

https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

But if want the information displayed in the upper right-hand corner of the terminal, I'm not aware of a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: terminal_bashrc]I am not sure what you are asking for.

Perhaps this screen shot will enlighten .

The top of each tab should by default show what directory or program you are running in that terminal.

Is this not what you were expecting? It is the same behavior as the default terminal for Mac OS.

I am not sure what is different on your default terminal in elementary from what you would expect. Cursor is controled by setting of the shell you chave chosen to use. e.g. bash in your example as well as mine. Perhaps man bash is in order or a google search on .bashrc.
[image: default terminal program with two tabs]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this is not exactly what I meant. The title you mentioned is the prompt configuration in the `~/.bashrc`  file under "PS1=...". Pantheon-terminal (like other terminals too) show this in tab title. What I mean is the gree-highlighted text in the top right of my screenshot. In the posted link you can configure it. If you have many open connections to other servers it can be very helpful and pretend you to fire a command on the wrong server.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I got similar results using [**Gnome-Terminal**](https://adam.merrifield.ca/2015/11/23/4-steps-to-replace-the-terminal-in-elementary-os-freya/) + [**Zsh**](https://ohmyz.sh/) + [**Spaceship Zsh Theme**](https://github.com/pascaldevink/spaceship-zsh-theme). The "badge" here is indicating the time and ruby/node environment versions. There's a lot of [**zsh themes**](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes).

[image]

Of course is not as straightforward as the iTerm, but you can play and find your own custom style.

[image]

Check the Gogh project as they share lots of Terminal Themes that you can use to create different profiles (light solarized, dark solarized etc.)
Gogh: https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh